# How do I exclude a path (/images) from single page app rewrite?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a react app and have the usual rewrite rule in firebase hosting:

```
   "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

I also have a separate /images directory with images I don't want to be rewritten.

How do I exclude the /images directory from the rewrite?

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit late but I found this question while searching for a similar problem.

Use this rewrites rule :

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "!/images/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

The key is that "source" (as a lot of fields in firebase.json) use a [glob pattern matching notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#section-glob).
Instead of redirecting everything on index.html (as do " ** "), this rule redirect everything **that is not** in the images folder and subfolders.

Comment: Not working for me
     `{
        "source": "/membership/**",
        "destination": "/membership/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "!/landing/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "!/membership/**",
        "destination": "index.html"
      }`

Comment: @dave-danuve Could you please describe what you are expecting ? For example your !landing & !membership couldn’t work together. Imagine « if (!landing) then throw exception else if (!membership) then throw exception »... That will always throw exception, even for landing or membership.

Comment: Ok, i've found your question and gave you an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297991/configure-redirects-on-firebase-hosting-spa-2-subfolders-firebase-json/52323990#52323990

Answer (score 2):

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/images/**",
      "destination": "/something.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

This will exclude everything inside your `/images` folder rewriting it to `/something.html`

Comment: Thank you but I want the images to be served from /images.  Is there are a way to do this?

Comment: maybe you can just rewrite each file in `/images` "to itself"